# Combine One array to several array

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge, array-combine

I have following content:

```
$staticArray = ['group_1', 'group_2'];

foreach ($staticArray as $name){
    $names[] = $name;
}

$staticArray2 = ['one', 'two'];

$i = 0;
foreach ($staticArray2 as $name){

    $item['group']['name']   = $names;
    $item['group']['user_1']   = 'Peter';
    $item['group']['user_2'] = 'Jack';

    $groups[] = $item;

    $i++;
}
```

The above code output is like this:

```
[ {
group: {
    name: [
       "group_1",
       "group_2",
       "group_1",
       "group_2"
   ],
    user_1: "Peter",
    user_2: "Jack"
   }
},

{
group: {
   name: [
      "group_1",
      "group_2",
      "group_1",
      "group_2"
   ],
   user_1: "Peter",
   user_2: "Jack"
  }
} ]
```

How can I edit first code to look like this:

```
{
   group: {
      name: "group_1", //group 1
      user_1: "Peter",
      user_2: "Jack"
   },
   group: {
      name: "group_2", //group 2
      user_1: "Peter",
      user_2: "Jack"
   }
}
```

**$staticArray** and **$staticArray2** is a two static variable, so these 2 items cannot be **editable.**

If you don't understand what I mean. Read this:

I have two array:

```
$legues = [ 'Laliga', 'Bundesliga', '...' ];

$teams  = [ 'FC Barcelona', 'RCD Mallorca', 'UD Levante', 'CF Valencia', 'FC Salzburg', 'WSG Tirol' ];
```

First league is "Laliga" and this league have 4 team: FC Barcelona , RCD Mallorca, UD Levante and CF Valencia.

Second league is "Bundesliga" and this league have 2 team: FC Salzburg and WSG Tirol.

Now I want to put this teams to the league (like my last output code).

Comment: Your item array looks like this, not what you have listed for the output: https://3v4l.org/sBdIZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$item['group']['name']   = $names;
```

with

```
$item['group']['name']   = $names[$i];
```

**[Example](https://3v4l.org/GUo7K)**

**Note:** *lengths of these static arrays should be the same.*

This move

```
$staticArray = ['group_1', 'group_2'];

foreach ($staticArray as $name){
    $names[] = $name;
}
```

doesn't makes sense. Your `$names` array equal to `$staticArray`. So, you can use `$staticArray` instead of `$names` array.

If you need to define a several values from `$staticArray2` to the first one (4,2 etc.) you need to define support array, like `[4,2]` and create specific loop for filling data in the `$groups`.

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZGHVp)**

Here `$sup` array should be the same length with `$legues`.

Comment: Thanks @Aksen P,

But i get Null or empty values or repeat League name.

Comment: @NicholRamires, I don't get it. What're you doing? Show your example

Comment: Look my image : https://i.ibb.co/cNS14Jk/sz.jpg

there are 3 arrays, home and away values always is dynamic.

anyway, your code is complete is true. but if you have other ways to get output like this. so can you tell me ?

Comment: @NicholRamires, how do you define league<>team pair?

Comment: @NicholRamires, you need to define `league` length with `$sup`, look at this [demo](https://3v4l.org/BThKi)

Comment: Yes, this demo i think it will work. i want to test. Very Thanks